# vue component is not passing events through

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have three nested components

```
<parent @event="handle">
  <inbetween @event="$emit('event')">
    <child> // emits event
    </child>
  </inbetween>
</parent>
```

so, when a child emits the event, I have to add that annoying part `@event="$emit('event')"` to the component inbetween, otherwise parent does not receive any event.

I hope it is not supposed to work that way. I wonder what could be wrong with it?

Comment: Yes thats how its supposed to work.  Event go only from child to parent, it does not go from child up to grand parent. Therefore you have to emit the event from both child and inbetween component.  If you want to avoid this method you can use Event Bus: https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/

Comment: Why do you want to use events? Why is everyone wedded to events? Please just stop using events!

Comment: @bbsimonbb what's so bad about events?

Comment: You've got a rolls royce mvvm library that will "automatically" synch your view and your model, so *use a model*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue custom events don't bubble.

The recommended way to handle ancestor/sibling communication in complex cases is using Vuex. If you have simple needs you can create Vue instance to use as event hub.

You would create a global variable:

```
var eventHub = new Vue(); // use a Vue instance as event hub
```

To emit events you would use in any component:

```
eventHub.$emit('myevent', 'some value');
```

And, to listen to that event, again, in any component, do:

```
eventHub.$on('myevent', (e) => {
    console.log('myevent received', e)
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var eventHub = new Vue(); // use a Vue instance as event hub

Vue.component('parent', {
    template: "#parent-tpl",
    created() {
      eventHub.$on('event', (e) => {
       console.log('event received at parent! value:', e);
      });
    }
});
Vue.component('inbetween', {
    template: "#inbetween-tpl"
});
Vue.component('child', {
    template: "#child-tpl",
    methods: {
      emitEvent() {
        eventHub.$emit('event', 123);
      }
    }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<template id="parent-tpl">
    <div>
        <inbetween></inbetween>
    </div>
</template>
<template id="inbetween-tpl">
    <div>
        <child></child>
    </div>
</template>
<template id="child-tpl">
    <div>
      <h1>I'm the child</h1>
      <button @click="emitEvent">Trigger EVENT</button>
    </div>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <parent></parent>
</div>
```

**Note:** If creating a dedicated instance as event hub is something complicated in your environment, you can replace `eventHub` with `this.$root` (inside your components) and use your own Vue instance as hub.

Comment: Hi, there, my problem is that I am using a nested component. Basically I am trying to create a tree view. For delete operation in need to send a delete message one step above. So that I can splice out the node itself. 

I noticed after reading that it is said that events can work on one level. That is from child to parent. 

But in the case of nested it is not working. 
This is my JSFiddle example. 
https://jsfiddle.net/shishirraven/oedr3u94/

Please suggest the best way to handle this. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually intentional. The reasoning is, when looking at the code for one component and you see that it's listening to an event, you can then look at the template to see where that event is coming from. If events could reach a component arbitrarily deep, it would be harder to figure out how and from where that event is being triggered.

However, Vue *used to* have a way of doing what you want to do, through the methods `$broadcast` and `$dispatch`, and they were eventually removed for the reasons talked about here. [Here's a page from the docs which explains why, along with possible solutions, such as using a global event bus, or a centralized state management solution such as Vuex.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#dispatch-and-broadcast-replaced)

Answer (score 3):

Yes thats how its supposed to work. Events go only from child to parent, it does not go from child up to grand parent. Therefore you have to emit the event from both child and inbetween component.

If you want to avoid this method you can use Event Bus:

https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/https-medium-com-andrejsabrickis-create-simple-eventbus-to-communicate-between-vue-js-components-cdc11cd59860

alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus

Comment: Hi, In a nested component of tree view. I need the message only to go one level up. Like from the the child to its immediate parent. 

Will the events work in such a relation or I should still need to go with other solutions such as eventBus or vuex. 

Thanks for taking out time to answer queries.

Comment: If the event needs to be emitted only to its direct parent, you can work with Events.  No need to use EventBus or Vuex